# 403 Forbidden on Windows 10 Pro after mklink htdocs/vhosts to Dropbox folder

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, ubuntu-12.04, dropbox

I've a Dropbox account / folder which is *sync*ed on both my laptops - one is a Ubuntu 12.04 and the other one is Windows 10 Pro.
I'm trying to configure my Apache on Windows to use the same folder location - Dropbox/vhosts

I ran cmd.exe as Admiistrator.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>cd C:\Apache24\htdocs

C:\Apache24\htdocs>mklink vhosts C:\Users\anjan\Dropbox\vhosts
symbolic link created for vhosts <<===>> C:\Users\anjan\Dropbox\vhosts
```

Now when I goto http://localhost/vhosts/site1 on the browser, I get a Forbidden message. The websites are loading on my Ubuntu machine.

What permissions are required on Windows ? Or is it the symlink that's wrong ?

Comment: This isn't really a Dropbox question is it? is vhosts a file or folder? with mklink should have a /j option to make a directory.

Comment: vhosts is a folder containing my sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you use the /D switch when making a symlink to a directory. `mklink` seems to make a 'file symlink' by default (even though its to a directory, strange) unless you specify this.

`mklink /D link-name target-directory`

Apache can't follow through to the directory contents if it's a 'file symlink'. Took me ages trawling the internet and digging deep into the system before I figured this out. One more IT jagged edge upon thousands. I'm posting this here since it needed to be on the internet somewhere and this was the closest question.

If even that doesn't work, you could try a Directory Junction with the /J switch.

`mklink /J link-name target-directory`